# Vim custom highlighting for lines starting with ;

Tags: vim, syntax, syntax-highlighting

I want to generate a custom highlighting rule for my template files `*.tmpl`, namely I would like to mark the lines that start with `;` - those are comment lines.

I have tried with something like this in my `.vimrc`

```
au BufRead,BufNewFile *.tmpl hi tmpl ctermfg=2 ctermbg=3
au BufRead,BufNewFile *.tmpl syn match tmpl /"\zs;\w*\ze"/
```

but it didn't work.

I use Vim 7.2 with `+syntax`.

That's my `.vimrc`

execute pathogen#infect()
set number

```
set clipboard=unnamedplus
set t_Co=256

syntax enable
set background=dark
let g:solarized_termcolors=256
colorscheme solarized

filetype plugin indent on

let g:Powerline_symbols = 'fancy'
set hlsearch

au BufRead,BufNewFile *.tmpl hi tmpl ctermfg=2 ctermbg=3
au BufRead,BufNewFile *.tmpl syn match tmpl /"\zs;\w*\ze"/
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

your regex:

```
/"\zs;\w*\ze"/
```

matches lines like this:

```
foo";commenttext"
";commenttext"bar
foo";commenttext"bar
```

but only `;commenttext` is highlighted.

if you want to have:

> I would like to mark the lines that start with ;

try this:

```
  syn match tmp /^\s*;\w*/
```

**note** that I used `\w*` instead of `.*` because you wrote it in your regex, I assume you want to match `\w` only. If you want to hi the whole line, no matter there is space (or other `\W`s) or not, use `.*`, for example:

```
  syn match tmp /^\s*;.*$/
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Worked perfectly.